# Android - Change channel for wave file from stereo to mono or mono to stereo using jni

Tags: android, java-native-interface, media, superpowered

I have used the Superpowered library to record audio. It records the audio in stereo. I want to change channel of recorded audio from stereo to mono. How can we change the audio channel for the recorded audio file using Superpowered or any other way?

Comment: Have you tried [`SuperpoweredStereoToMono`](http://superpowered.com/docs/_superpowered_simple_8h.html#a2e4fd6699e3ca40320333d5e14c014e3)?

Comment: Thanks @Michael for your suggestion. As you suggest I implemented the SuperpoweredStereoToMono. It changes the audio channel but slow down the audio too with noise. But i don't want to change the quality for the audio just want to change channel from stereo to mono as ffmpeg do.

Comment: Probably will be helpful for someone. Latest version of Superpowered seems support Mono recording http://superpowered.com/recorder-filter-progressive-download-improvements

Answer (score 2):

SuperpoweredRecorder always records in stereo.

Comment: I know SuperpoweredRecorder records the track in stereo but i want to convert it to mono

Comment: Superpowered can't help with that.

Comment: @GaborSzanto what about using `SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO` ? not help to record audio in mono?

Comment: The SuperpoweredRecorder needs stereo input data, sorry.